# right floated div...align to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I've got html like so:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <img alt="Track System" src="Images/myimage.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="11Models2.aspx">Models</a></li>
                        <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Lease.aspx">Lease </a></li>
                        <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The first div (The one float-left) is just an image that has some length to it...
The second div (the float-right) are tabs that I want to align on the bottom.  Right now they are too high up...

the css classes simply are:

```
.float-left{
float:left;
}

.float-right{
float:right;
}
```

I tried changing to absolute and relative positioning but it did not help...
[image]

Here's what it looks like with the logo correctly being displayed on the left but the tabs on the right floating...I'd like to get those aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Please provide a working jsfiddle with all CSS affecting the image and tags

Comment: @Oriol here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/86Pr2/

Comment: See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86Pr2/1/

Comment: Notice the tabs are at the top, I want to move them to the bottom edge right before the content of the div.

Comment: @ImranOmer this is not right, your tabs are at the bottom of the page.  I want the tabs to appear before the gray section at the top right.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, does simply setting the top margin on the right-floated element seems to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/86Pr2/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/86Pr2/4/

I added a div with a class of "clear" and the following CSS: (I added !important to all of them cause I didn't feel like looking through all your code.)

```
.float-right {
position:absolute !important;
bottom:0 !important;
right:0 !important;
}
.content-wrapper {
   position:Relative !important;
}
.clear {
    clear:both !important;
}
```

And the changed HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <img alt="Track System" src="http://i.imgur.com/2M3DyCv.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="11Models2.aspx">Models</a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Lease.aspx">Lease </a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>    
<div class="clear"><!--This makes the wrapper have a height--></div>

    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        hi
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wahoo! Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not that @codedude didn't create something that would work but you wouldn't ever want to use the !important tag in your CSS.

Here's what I was working on: http://jsfiddle.net/dancameron/86Pr2/7/

It doesn't require any additional markup either (an empty div to clear!) and cleans up the class names to be more semantic.

HTML:

```
 <div class="content-wrapper clear-fix">
        <div class="float-left">
            <img alt="Track System" src="http://i.imgur.com/2M3DyCv.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrap">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="11Models2.aspx">Models</a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Lease.aspx">Lease </a></li>
                    <li class="tab"><a runat="server" href="Help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            hi
        </section>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-wrap nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```